# What makes L unique in "Love," and what is her significance?

Tags: love, toni-morrison

Toni Morrison's *Love* is narrated by L, who lives on the beach, and seems to be the only person around who truly understood Bill Cosey.

> I pay attention and I know all about him. That kind of understanding can only come from practice, and I had a lot of that with Mr. Cosey. You could say I fathomed his mind.

But L, throughout the story and backstory both, is removed from the action. She's often mentioned as a quiet voice of reason, and a twist near the end has her hand in it -- but it seems we never really learn who L is, what *her* relationship to Cosey was, and why it is that she alone has such insight.

What do we actually know about L? Is any justification for her uniqueness given -- do we get any sense of why *she* is a reliable guide and narrator, when all the other characters are wrapped up in their flaws and histories? What structural or thematic role does her character fulfill in the book?